# Why aren't my InfoPath buttons displaying correctly and how can I fix them?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, browsers

I have A SharePoint Online list with a New Item form I have customised with InfoPath. The functionality is simple. A serial number is entered into a text box and if it matches one fot he serial numbers in a connected lookup list, the details of all items with that number are displayed in a repeating section with with a button which can be clicked to select an item and update the form with its details.

The design looks likes this:
[image]

All the infopath functionality works but when I open the form in my organizations standard browser (IE9 64bit) It displays like this:

[image]

Does anyone know why the button is displaying as a flat line? The Submit button at the bottom of the page is displaying normally.

PS: There is no possibility of switching to a different browser for technical and security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

It could be IE 64 bit, you should try with IE 32 bit just to assure that this is the cause. Have you tried increase the height of the button in Infopath? Also, you can try using an image button (instead of the chromed silver button).

Comment: I've tried 32bit and get the same result. I hadn't thought of altering the button height though. Thanks, I'll try that next!